# ImportError : No module named face_recognition when running via GUI

Tags: python, face-recognition

I want to a run script that contains face_recognition. It ran perfectly when I ran it via IDE, but when I execute the same script using the GUI button which uses the os. system('./run.py), it shows the following error.

```
ImportError : No module named face_recognition
```

I have installed Cmake,dlib correctly. And also I've checked GUI method on Windows It's not showing that error on windows. I can't figure out the reason for this.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python by any chance?

Comment: I think there maybe. I tested it on raspberry pi.

Comment: You need to install the `face-recognition` library using `pip install face-recognition` on the system you are trying to run it.